# how to get a value of the state and manipulate it without changing the state itself in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm developing an app with react native. I have an array of object in the state (lettersPosition) and I want to sort it temporally in a variable within a function (but I don't want the state itself to be sorted) :

```
verifyWord = () => {
    const array = this.state.lettersPosition;       
    array.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.x - b.x;
    });
    var word = "";
    array.map(function (char) {
        word += char.letter
    })
}
```

I tested it and it appears that my state itself was updated after the sorting (even if I called the sort function on the temp array).

It is like if the 'array' variable contains the whole reference to the state and not only its value. And if I modify that variable, it modifies the state too.

Is it a normal behaviour in react ?

How can I just get the value of the state and manipulate it without changing the state itself ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). It creates a shallow copy.

```
const sortedArray = Array.from(this.state.lettersPosition);
...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var newArray = oldArray.slice();` rather than  `const array = this.state.lettersPosition;` In your code you're not creating a copy of the array, you're just assigning it to another variable.

See [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value) for more info on `var newArray = oldArray.slice();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator too.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var b = [...a]
```